# Find random point along a line

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, geometry

I'm writing a small program to help split passwords ( see below for explanation)

I have code to convert text to a int ( text-ascii binary -> dec int)

so in this case the word "test" would = 1952805748

Now the interesting part.(encoding the password)

I would then take x1 = 1952805748 and y1 = 0

then i make up a random point where x2 = 7 and y2 = 142

this will draw a line between x1,y1 and x2,y2  (using Y=mx+B)

I need to how find any random point along the line that these two points create (well call that x3,y3)

If anyone has any ideas i would love to hear them. Im trying to work out the code that both points are ints ( its easier on everyone if we dont have huge decimal points behind each number)

++ The why ++

the general idea is that if you had to split up a password between two parties that one party could possibly figure out the password based on the string they were given

if you use this method they would get a single point each and from that single point it would be mathmaticly impossible to deterimine where the line meets x (x=? y =0)
so you could feel safe handing one set of points to your lawyer and one to your wife

they would do the math (entering it into a program) then they would get a number that would be decode to say a password that could decrpt a file with your will or some other sensitve document that you wouldnt want them to access with out the other preseent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This algorithm is actually called "[Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing)" and is a really good way of splitting up secrets. You can split up arbitrarily large secrets which require whichever number of people you want to come together to recover the secret.

I would suggest you generalize slightly and go for a solution that will let you specify that N points are required to solve for the N-1 degree polynomial. You can use [Lagrange Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) to solve this for you.

The pseudo code at Wikipedia, however, is only good for floats, and needs to be modified slightly for use with integers. [Check out my full python implementation](http://gist.github.com/585345) if you want some ideas (and assuming it is at all helpful).

It gives me this output:

```
1 -- 50383220533284199945706810754936311181214547134666382315016772033813961148457676
2 -- 125723425896904546349739165166331731432281836699962161072279259011758052396215820
3 -- 235794378436564714387676526976517945151880763730707233042654663244625708155520494
'This is my super secret password.'
```

***Edit:*** A year later I have updated the implementation to work within a finite field, which is required for it to be provably secure. Hooray!

Comment: I'm just happy to know it has an actual name.  I'll see if i can implement it in c#

Answer (score 8):

Other answers have addressed your mathematical idea, but on the encryption front I would *strongly* recommend that you don't try to work out your own encryption scheme.

If you want to encrypt something with two passwords such that both are necessary, there's a much easier way to do it: encrypt the file twice:

```
Plaintext -> Encrypted1 (with password 1)
Encrypted1 -> Encrypted2 (with password 2)
```

`Encrypted2` is what you store. Throw away `Encrypted1`.

To decrypt, just decrypt `Encrypted2` with password 2 to get `Encrypted1`, then decrypt `Encrypted1` to get back to the plaintext.

Either password on its own is useless, just as intended, and you don't need to work out *any* encryption algorithms/code.

EDIT: As an even simpler solution, just make up a really long password and give each party half of it. For instance, encrypt the file with the key "this is a very long password" and give your wide "this is a very" and your lawyer " long password". Obviously you need to choose the password appropriately so that knowing one half doesn't give any hints about the other.

Comment: i acknowledge there are different ways of doing this.  however lets say the password was in fact password

I i gave you the phrase "pass" worst case senerio you could figure out what it was, best case is you would be halfway to brute forcing the password that is now half as secure.

Comment: So instead of the original password, convert the password into some big binary hash in a predictable but non-reversible manner. Use that hash as the key for the real encryption, and split the hash. There are plenty of ways round this without inventing your own encryption schemes based on geeometry.

Comment: And you're getting personal instructions from the smartest guy on the block and disregarding them, lol!

Comment: The problem with your edit is that every chunk of the password is actually a chunk of the password, and brings whomever is collecting them that much closer to having the secret. Optimally, you should be able to have 99% of the secret, and not be able to make ANY headway on it.

Comment: @Job Skeet: This is actually a proven scheme for secret sharing. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing

Comment: @mike boers: No, you are wrong. If there are two 8 digit passwords needed to unlock, and you know one of them, that doesn't help you know the other 8 digit password. You still need to brute force all 8 digits, regardless of which of the two methods are used.

Comment: this is all true but not in the scope of the question

Comment: @Crash893: I make it a point to tell people when I think they're barking up an inappropriate tree. It can save a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @Mike Boers: I was addressing the edit as well. Having a 16 digit key split in two is the same as having two 8 digit keys, as long as they are independent. That was the point I was trying to make.

Answer (score 4):

If your endpoints are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and you have a random number r int the range 0 through 1, the point along the line will be:

```
(x1+(x2-x1)*r,y1+(y2-y1)*r)
```

With your given endpoints (1952805748,0) and (7,42) with a random value 0.5 (halfway along the line), you end up with:

```
(976402877.5,21)
```

which you can easily work out as the midpoint. You can round any co-ordinates if you need integers.

Following your comment (paraphrased):

`I may not have explained this properly: one person would be given (x1,y1) different person would be given (x3,y3). At no point would a person be able to take a single point and figure out where the line crosses x (N,0).`

Given that your (x1,y1) was (1952805748,0), whoever has that know the intersection of the x-axis (since y = 0). It sounds like you want two points along the line where neither are on the x-axis. That means one party should be given your randomly chosen end-point (7,42) and the other party your random point on the line (976402877.5,21) - neither of those point should have a y-value of zero. This could be acheived by ensuring the random value was in the range .2 to 1.0 rather than 0.0 to 1.0 (assuming your y1 is always 0).

Neither of the parties could work out the x-axis intersect with their one co-ordinate but the two co-ordinates combined would give you that information.

Also, in that case, rounding or ordinates would not be suitable, you would have to map them, for example (976402877.5,21) becoming (1952805755,42) [multiply by 2, which is the simplest integer ratio].

Comment: I may not have explained this properly

1) one person would be given x1y1 different person would be given x3 y3 at no point would a person be able to take a single point and figure out where the line crosses x ( x=whatever, y=0)

Is the P3 could be between p1+p2 or it could anywhere along the line

Comment: See update. Basically neither of the points given out should have y=0.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Assume x1, x2, and m, b exist as ints
Random r = new Random();
int x3 = r.Next(Math.Min(x1, x2), Math.Max(x1, x2));
int y3 = m * x3 + b;
```

Basically, we pick some x between the two xs (guaranteeing the correct domain, and by constraints on your linear function, the correct range) and solve it for y. Not too difficult.

Comment: this looks like it might be the answer. I will give it a try when I get back to work.

Comment: Except that it picks an integer x value and *assumes* it'll produce an integer y value. I don't believe that's going to be accurate.

Comment: @jon skeet: if m/x3/b are integer, the properties of multiplication and addition ensure that this will always produce an integer.

Comment: @SnOrfus we really have zero reason to believe m and b are integer.  The calculation that m is generated from is highly likely to generate decimal results.   What we can do is round the values off, but that might cause a problem for the decryptor.

Comment: @Karl is right, you just have to see the test data and the formula it generates (y = -0.0000007271588618x + 142.0000005) to know that integers will be nowhere near sufficient for this. Decryption will be impossible since the values 0 and 142 will not be able to do it.

Comment: I know how to find slope but how would i find B?

Comment: See here for my answer on solving for three unknowns. Two is substantially easier but the same concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769/solving-a-linear-equation/590060#590060

Comment: I addressed his actual question knowing that 50 other people would point out the myriad of things wrong with it. I stand by my (admittedly stupid) answer.

Answer (score 1):

One wouldn't have to solve for some unknown coordinate.. One would simply have to plug your encrypted file into a sequential number generator.  You have effectively reduced the complexity of brute-forcing the encryption by several times.  Instead of each character being 1 of ~94 (typable characters on a standard keyboard), you've reduced it to 1 in 10 (1 in 11 if you allow decimals).

I would advise against this method.  As Skeeter mentioned, just encrypt the file twice.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the "Number" that this program find would be decode into ascii text which would be used as the password. so password complexity stays intact.(all 95 printable chars)

I don't see how this would be any different having a regular password