# Least Square Method 3D

Tags: java, linear-algebra

Is there anything that can give me the best fitting plane (I'm talking about Java libraries or anything usefull), given a set of N points ? I have to say that the coordinates are not realted, I mean that z = f(x,y) is not true. Anything usefull would be ok. I have to use this stuff in Java.

I know it might be a tough or too generic question, and I'm sorry about it.

Answer (score 0):

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400213/3d-least-squares-plane) covered this.

Here's an [implementation](http://codesuppository.blogspot.com/2006/03/best-fit-plane.html) though it's in C++ not Java.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I know both. The previous question is actually confusing me. But now that I'm thinking, maybe I can use PCA and find the principal components and then find the plane given these princpal directions. I'm considering this solution because I've already implemented PCA algorithm.