# What's the best algorithm/paper on finding the closest/nearest plane from a set of points in space?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d

Given a point cloud, what's the best way to find the closest plane that's fairly accurate but also fast enough?

I searched for nearest plane but couldn't find any related info.

I want to use this to snap them to this plane.

Comment: You could start from building a line like here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression, which is the 2d counterpart of your objective

Comment: Do you mean one of the "primary" planes (XY, XZ, YZ, with some Z, Y, or X offset, respectively), or determine the plane most closely described by the set of points?

Comment: @DavidEllis: the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could also do this using principal component analysis:

Compute the average of your points:

```
C = (0,0,0);
for each point Ri in your dataset,
  { C += Ri; }
C = C * 1.0 / npoints;
```

Compute the covariance matrix of your points:

```
A = zeros(3,3);
for each point Ri in your dataset,
  {
  D = Ri - C;
  A += D*D';  // outer product
  }
```

Compute the inverse of A, A_inv:

```
  A_inv = inv(A)
```

Perform power iterations by repeatedly applying A_inv to a random initial vector:

```
  N = random vector.
  for i=1:20 (or so)
    {
    N = A_inv*N;
    N = normalize(N);
    }
```

The offset from the origin to your plane is k = dot(N,C). The equation that describes your plane is all points R such that k = dot(N,R).

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how to calculate these 2 principal vectors though. Do you have any example?

Comment: I will take a crack at it - overflow noob here.

Comment: Thanks man, I will try your implementation in a moment. Although I am not sure of the last line. Power methods, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Can you please also show how to get the most dominant eigenvectors? I haven't used them before.

Comment: Based on an answer from the other thread that duffymo linked, it does makes more sense to find N directly via inverse iteration than to compute P1, P2 and then look for their orthogonal complement. I think A is guaranteed to be symmetric positive definite (thus invertible) as long as you have 3 non collinear points.

Comment: yeah, it makes a lot more sense.  It's hard for me to see how this solution is better.   calculating the full inverse does not seem to be a good idea - it's likely to be overrun with roundoff errors.

Comment: A is only 3x3, makes it a little better. You can always replace the explicit inverse calculation with any "inverse-revealing" decomposition (LU, for instance - backsolving by L then by U is equivalent to applying the inverse but generally cheaper and more accurate - can do the same kinds of tricks with QR, SVD). You have a good point though - if your points are truly well approximated by a plane, then A is close to a matrix of low rank. An eigen or SVD decomposition is the best way to "invert" A. I do think the "first" PCA algorithm (N=P1xP2) is more robust in the face of near singular A.

Comment: Just one more comment, it's exactly the singularity of A that you are really trying to find/measure. The nullspace of A (if it's singular) or it's least dominant eigen/singular vector (if it's close to singular) is the normal of the sought plane. That fact that PCA/SVD explicitly separates/orthogonalizes these spaces is (IMO) a good thing.

Comment: Wouldn't A be 4x4?  There's a constant plus one coefficient for each of x, y, and z.  And yes, LU or anything else is likely to be better than inversion.

Comment: A is indeed 3x3. There are 4 unknowns, but we just compute the normal (x,y,z) using PCA. The fourth unknown (offset from the origin) is postprocessed. Also, was too late to edit - that "A is invertible iff it was built from 3 non collinear points" comment should instead be "4 non coplanar points".

Answer (score 4):

Least squares regression would be my guess.  It will give you the coefficients for the plane that minimizes the mean square error over all the points.

You aren't the first:

[3D Least Squares Plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400213/3d-least-squares-plane)

Comment: Do you know any examples specific for this or any example I can use to modify for my case? I heard of least squares but never used it before.