# matplotlib plot a surface plane to see which point not on the plane

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, surface

Right now I have a scatter 3D plot and all three variables x, y, z are independent variables. I want to fit a surface plane to see roughly which point is an outlier, not on the plane.

My script looks like this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
from matplotlib import cm


x_axis = np.array([-1.0421, 0.628354, 8.79899, 0.359502, -0.952719, -0.54148, 
          0.604585, 0.739086, 8.62336, 6.29254, 1.3942, 3.82348, -0.214241, 
          4.86446, 2.56733, 2.97113, -0.395414, 0.848251])


y_axis=np.array([-1131.02, -1111.02, -1076.85, -1125.94, -1140.41, -1130.37, -1114.58,
        -1148.05, -1103.2, -1109.89, -1131.98, -1114.59, -1093.26, -1108.23,
        -1121.88, -1111.72, -1143.87, -1126.38])

z_axis =np.array([0.76, 0.75, 0.12, 1.07, 1.06, 0.63, 0.14, 0.79, 0.16, 0.14, 0.81, 0.36, 0.09,
        0.26, 0.51, 0.28, 0.92, 0.66])

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(9, 7), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, c='brown', marker='o', s=25)
plt.show()
```

My plot looks like this: 
[image]

My whole takeaway is just to see how many outliers there are and how "good" the points can form a surface. If there are only 2 or 3 outliners, I can tell x, y, z have a strong correlation. My point is just to see if three of them form a correlation.

Comment: If it is not the points themselves that define the surface, what else would it be? What is the property of the surface and according to what data do you want to draw it? At the moment this does not seem like a programming question at all.

Comment: So what is it then that you want? Plot a plane together with your scatter plot? Fit a surface to your data? Both?

Comment: I want to fit a surface plot to my scatter plot

Comment: Great, but what function would you like to fit? A plane, a tilted plane, some more complex function?

Comment: A tilted plane would be the best.

Comment: Great, so what is the problem of plotting a tilted plane in the above plot?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35070178/2454357)