# Fitting function to multiple datasets in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am having a problem where I have dataset A and dataset B, and I know that the data in A obeys, say f(a,b,c), while the data in B obeys g(a,b,d) and I want to fit the data so that I obtain the best fit for my parameters. Unfortunately I could not find a function in SciPy to do this.

For context I have data for T(N) and T(r) and both obey some T(a,b,c,r,N) but I can't fit my data as I can't fit them separetely as I would get different results that way, however scipy.optimize.curve_fit only takes one set of data.

Comment: how about [scipy optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)? ... more precise the curve fit module...

Comment: It takes only one set of data unfortunately(curve_fit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I was looking at it the wrong way. Solution can be found here: [Fit plane to a set of points in 3D: scipy.optimize.minimize vs scipy.linalg.lstsq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070178/fit-plane-to-a-set-of-points-in-3d-scipy-optimize-minimize-vs-scipy-linalg-lsts?rq=1)