# RANSAC plane fitting coefficients

Tags: point-cloud-library, ransac

I am trying to fit a plane to a set of point cloud. I tried using Point Cloud Library (PCL) & it works well. What I need to know is that how can I obtain the coefficients a,b,c of the fitted plane (ax+by+cz+1=0). Is there any straightforward way? I got some insights from here: [3D Least Squares Plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400213/3d-least-squares-plane)

Comment: ask this question on crossvalidated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the following planar segmentation tutorial:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/planar_segmentation.php

Note in particular the use of the `pcl::ModelCoefficients` data structure.

Allocation:

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
```

Use:

```
seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
```

Meaning:

`coefficients->values[0]/coefficients->values[3]` is your **a**.

`coefficients->values[1]/coefficients->values[3]` is your **b**.

`coefficients->values[2]/coefficients->values[3]` is your **c**.

See also:

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_model_coefficients.html