# Calculating and Plotting Principal Components using Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, pca, principal-components

I have an image. I need to identify the axis along which the variance of the image is the smallest. A bit of reading and searching led me to the conclusion that Principal Component Analysis(PCA) is the best alternative. Can anyone help me with orienting the image with respect to its principal axis? Since i am recently introduced to matlab i find it a bit difficult. An example of the image is below. I am trying to rotate the image so that i can generate the histogram.

[image]

I haven't used PCA as yet my current code is as shown below

```
enter code here
I2='image'
I11= bwlabel(I2);
OBB = imOrientedBox(I11);
obbsize=[];
for i=1:size(OBB,1)
   obbsize=[obbsize,OBB(i,3)*OBB(i,4)];
end
[a,i]=max(obbsize);
I11=(imrotate(I2,OBB(i,5)));
imshow(I11,[])

[pks,locs] =findpeaks(sum(I11,2));
[M1,Indx1] = max(pks);
imshow(I11(1:locs(Indx1),1:size(I11,2)),[])
```

Comment: What is your input data?  The coordinates subject to rotation?  Is your image being rotated with respect to the origin, or is there an offset?  There isn't enough information to help you solve your problem.  Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi, I will update the question.

Comment: Ahh ok.  So is it my understanding that you have a set of coordinates, and you want to reproject the coordinates onto the basis vectors to remove the rotation?  It's pretty unclear from your diagram.  Also, some code and/or the raw images that you're using would certainly be useful to help you solve your problem.  Right now, I can't do anything.

Comment: Also, you can use `regionprops` and determine the angle of orientation and simply apply `imrotate` in the reverse direction to rotate the image.  It's not necessary to use PCA out of the box.

Comment: I added my code and the picture i use.  regionprops  gives really bad results.

Comment: It looks like your shape is subject to 3D rotation.  Is that true?

Comment: Okay the PCA issue has been solved before and it's as simple as obtaining a rotation matrix for your projection to your PC...

Comment: Actually you don't even need a rotation matrix. the `PCA` function gives you the transformation and you can always create an inverse transformation afterwards >.>

Comment: [coeff,score,latent,tsquared] = pca(___) so what do i use and how?

Comment: @rayryeng i m looking for least change in variance in image. hence PCA.

Comment: With respect to what?  The directionality of the shape? The intensities of the image?

Comment: I posted a short answer as to how to use PCA and return it to the original transformation which appears to be what you want. Can you clarify if this is correct?

Comment: With respect to least change in variation in intensity of image

Comment: @rayryeng Are you familiar with PCA?

Comment: @krisdestruction - Yes.  I tried using it to solve an algorithmic problem I had a couple of weeks ago.  It didn't work so I used something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550785/algorithm-to-group-sets-of-points-together-that-follow-a-direction

Comment: @rayryeng Okay I presumed you knew, just wanted to make sure!

Comment: @user2307268 The rotation matrix `C` should be self explainatory. Let me know if you need any clarification on the issue.

Comment: @user2307268 Updated my answer with the **least** amount of variance

Comment: I have worked with PCA before. But orientation is all new to me. I know the basic theory.@krisdestruction

Comment: @user2307268 That's okay, did it solve your issue? I'm not sure what you want with the histogram, but perhaps with this new transformed space, it would solve your issue? Perhaps you can clarify that histogram part.

Comment: @krisdestruction - Haha no worries.  Good job on your post though. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks, I tried to find PCA duplicate posts, but I couldn't find any in a limited time. I think this is a good post to refer to in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct your PCA transformation matrix using. C is your transformation or your rotation matrix that will transform it to your highest variance directions.

```
[C,~,~,~,explained] = pca( data );
```

Remove PC if you wish to truncate components (say 1-5 components). If you don't need to truncate/reduce dimensions, ignore this step.

```
C = C(:,1:5);
```

Create the transformed data using the transformation `C`. The data will now be in the new transformed space with the **first** dimension being the **largest** variance, **second** dim being the **second largest** variance, etc. Since you are looking for the **least variance**, that is the **last** dimension

```
tfData = data * C;
```

Process your data accordingly in this new transformed space. To obtain your inverse transformation and put it back to the original space, use the following.

```
origAxisData = tfData * C';
```

The transpose operation `C'` is the same as the inverse operation `inv(C)` for the inverse transformation as it is orthogonal [as described here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34724/reversing-pca-back-to-the-original-variables). However the transpose is much faster to calculate than the inverse, especially for high dimensions.

You can plot your principal component/axes/kernel by plotting the columns of C as follows.

```
for i = 1:length(end)
    figure; plot( C(:,1) );
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have a bit more work to do and things to understand. Ill update you when i am done. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing, accept it if it's correct, or let me know if it needs any changes!

Comment: Since you asked, you can plot the axes with the above code, although that's generally more for higher dimensions (eg. mine is 1000 dimensions).

Comment: Hi, I wet through PCA. Can i directly apply PCA on an image or do i need to restructure it?

Comment: Well that depends on the variance you're trying to capture. If you're trying to get the maximum variance of neighbouring x-y pixels, you will need to extract neighbouring pixel values. Regardless of what approach you want to take, you will need to put the dimensions of variance you want to capture and put it into a feature vector with rows representing each sample dataset, and columns representing feature values in each dimension you are measuring.