# How can I segment curved text lines?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, text-segmentation

I am looking a way to segment an image that has curved text lines. I need to segment the image in a way that I can access and manipulate each of the lines individually. I don't want to deskew the lines yet, but have already performed gaussian smoothing on the whole image to remove the noise. I am pretty new to image processing and any help would be appreciated. Here is the input file image that I am using:

[image: input image]

Comment: Is it my understanding that you want to segment out the text from the background?  I'm not sure I understand your problem statement.

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to do.. But handle each line individually.. The attached image is input one and gaussian smoothing is performed on it. I tried using bounding box on it but the results that I get are not what I expected.. Instead it was bounding each and every word in the text taking each of them as different connected component..

Comment: Have a look at this post for insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550785/algorithm-to-group-sets-of-points-together-that-follow-a-direction - It's a different problem, but it's definitely a start in the right direction with where you'll want to head.  Basically, take each character and represent them by their centre location, then use the algorithm that's written in that post to group things together that follow a warped line.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much.. I would try that..