# How to automate editing of x,y-path

Tags: python, opencv

This is a pretty abstract questions, and isn't necessarily attached to a language/module. Sorry for the lack of specifics.

I'm making an object-tracing program in Python (for my biology lab I work for) using OpenCV. So far, I'm converting microscope videos into frames and then detecting the organisms swimming around.

The videos have lots of buggers that look like this:

[image: microscopic worm in crescent formation]

I have successfully found ways to get x,y-paths that can outline these. When successful, it looks like this (where the x,y-path is the border around the green):

[image: Correct mask of the first worm]

However, quite frequently, I get x,y-paths that look more like this:

[image: Improper mask]

As you can see, the x,y-path encompasses much but not all of the edges of the worm. I'll call this improper path an "edge mask". What I need is the second picture. I could explain to any human how to recognize this edge mask ('extreme' concavity, looping in on itself), but I'm struggling to find an algorithm that would be able to take the x,y-path in the third image and return something close to that in the second. Any ideas?

In python, the x,y-paths that make up the green masks above are stored like this in my program:

```
lst = [x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, ..., xn, yn]
```

...where the (`xn`, `yn`) point is treated like it also wraps around and connects with the (`x0`, `y0`) point. I'm using this form, but it is easy to convert it to a list of tuples if necessary.

What I'm imagining is some kind of algorithm that would be able to identify the parts of the path that are completely "contained" (so to speak) by the rest of the path, aka the x,y points that are on the inside of the mask (like the red part in the picture below). If I could identify an algorithm that can identify the points on the red path and delete them, then the path would correctly contain/mask the worm.

[image: Red on the inner edge of the mask]

One issue I'm seeing: Concavity alone won't help here. The worm itself is bent, and its right edge is completely concave, so I can't use concavity alone to identify the red line in the image above.

I would attach code, but the code I have is not the problem, it's finding an algorithm to adjust the *output* of the code I'm using. I believe my question shouldn't require & can't provide a minimum reproducible example. I think that's why they say "When appropriate..." in reference to using mre. Thanks!

---

After I've posted this, I've been thinking about it and I think I have one idea of what to do and I'd like to hear what people think:

For each x,y point on the path, I can check with evenly spaced rays to see approximately what % of rays intercept with another part of the path. The points on the red edge in the fourth picture above would have a much lower % of "escaping" rays than those on the outside, and even lower than those on the concave right side of the worm. I could delete points having a low % of escaping rays (using an arbitrary threshold) and the path would be fine. Thoughts?

---

Example raw data:

```
lst = [17, 297, 17, 303, 15, 305, 15, 309, 16, 310, 17, 310, 20, 313, 21, 313, 32, 324, 32, 326, 33, 326, 35, 328, 38,
       328, 39, 327, 39, 323, 38, 322, 37, 322, 36, 321, 36, 320, 35, 319, 35, 313, 36, 312, 42, 312, 43, 313, 44, 313,
       45, 314, 46, 314, 47, 315, 50, 315, 51, 316, 52, 316, 53, 317, 54, 317, 55, 318, 56, 318, 57, 319, 58, 319, 59,
       320, 60, 320, 62, 322, 63, 322, 67, 326, 70, 326, 74, 330, 75, 330, 78, 333, 79, 333, 83, 337, 83, 338, 84, 339,
       84, 340, 85, 340, 92, 347, 93, 347, 95, 349, 96, 349, 99, 352, 100, 352, 106, 358, 106, 359, 110, 363, 110, 364,
       112, 366, 113, 366, 116, 369, 117, 369, 119, 371, 119, 378, 118, 379, 112, 379, 110, 377, 109, 377, 105, 373,
       104, 373, 93, 362, 92, 362, 88, 358, 88, 357, 87, 357, 81, 351, 80, 351, 77, 348, 76, 348, 67, 339, 66, 339, 61,
       334, 60, 334, 58, 332, 57, 332, 56, 331, 55, 331, 54, 330, 48, 330, 48, 333, 49, 333, 50, 334, 51, 334, 52, 335,
       53, 335, 61, 343, 62, 343, 69, 350, 70, 350, 73, 353, 74, 353, 75, 354, 75, 355, 76, 355, 82, 361, 83, 361, 85,
       363, 85, 364, 86, 365, 87, 365, 99, 377, 100, 377, 104, 381, 105, 381, 107, 383, 108, 383, 109, 384, 111, 384,
       113, 386, 114, 386, 116, 388, 117, 388, 118, 389, 120, 389, 121, 390, 121, 392, 122, 393, 123, 393, 124, 394,
       125, 394, 126, 395, 127, 395, 128, 396, 128, 397, 129, 398, 130, 398, 133, 401, 142, 401, 143, 400, 143, 399,
       144, 398, 144, 394, 143, 393, 143, 389, 140, 386, 140, 385, 138, 383, 137, 383, 132, 378, 132, 377, 131, 376,
       130, 376, 128, 374, 128, 373, 127, 372, 127, 371, 119, 363, 118, 363, 114, 359, 114, 358, 113, 358, 110, 355,
       110, 353, 106, 349, 105, 349, 103, 347, 102, 347, 99, 344, 98, 344, 90, 336, 89, 336, 88, 335, 88, 334, 87, 333,
       87, 332, 85, 330, 84, 330, 81, 327, 80, 327, 79, 326, 78, 326, 76, 324, 75, 324, 73, 322, 72, 322, 68, 318, 67,
       318, 65, 316, 64, 316, 63, 315, 62, 315, 61, 314, 60, 314, 59, 313, 58, 313, 57, 312, 56, 312, 55, 311, 52, 311,
       51, 310, 50, 310, 49, 309, 48, 309, 47, 308, 46, 308, 45, 307, 44, 307, 43, 306, 42, 306, 41, 305, 40, 305, 39,
       304, 32, 304, 32, 308, 31, 309, 25, 309, 24, 308, 24, 302, 25, 301, 28, 301, 28, 299, 27, 299, 26, 298, 22, 298,
       21, 297]
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code you're using to extract these "x-y" paths?  I don't know if the final output is a list of coordinates or is a mask.  If it's a mask, try performing some morphology to the image, such as closing with an appropriately shaped mask.  Once you give us more details, I can provide a solution that is tailored towards your expected inputs and outputs.  Also as per Stack Overflow guidelines, you are expected to provide a [mcve].  Please adhere to these guidelines.

Comment: @rayryeng I've adjusted my question above, hopefully I've explained myself well. as far as the example code goes, if it's wrong for me to ask questions finding algorithms here, that's fine and I'd be fine to let this go. Thanks!

Comment: Just added a bit more again, this time below the horizontal line. I think it's a good example of the kind of help I'm looking for.

Comment: What will be really helpful is to see how you ID the original paths. There may be a lot of room for improvement there.

Comment: I'm open to the idea that I could have a lot to clarify here. Let me ask, is my edit with the `lst` variable insufficient in showing how I'm IDing the paths? If so, could you help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: What's the input image you are working with? The first one you posted? It might be useful if you also post your raw (unprocessed) input.

Comment: @eldesgraciado Thanks for the suggestion, I just posted some. It's the data used in the first example in my answer below. I'd be happy to receive pointers on my answer (or better, not-so-computationally-intensive solutions).

Comment: @MilesRobertson Questions about algorithms are definitely on-topic here.  For example, have a look at one question I asked several years ago.  It was an algorithm to find a group of points provided that they are along the same directional axis.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550785/algorithm-to-group-sets-of-points-together-that-follow-a-direction.  As long as you show us what you did and where you're having difficulties, these are most definitely on topic.  I also appreciate the answer you posted.  I'm favouriting this now.  Thanks so much for your contribution to our community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and coded my idea that I had and it seems to be working well so far. Borrowed from [this page](https://bryceboe.com/2006/10/23/line-segment-intersection-algorithm/) about finding if two line segments intersect.

```py
def ccw(A, B, C):
    return (C[1]-A[1]) * (B[0]-A[0]) > (B[1]-A[1]) * (C[0]-A[0])


# Return true if line segments AB and CD intersect
def intersect(A, B, C, D):
    return ccw(A, C, D) != ccw(B, C, D) and ccw(A, B, C) != ccw(A, B, D)


def rayEscape(point, degree, path, radius, indx=-1):
    """Returns True if a ray going from 'point' at an angle of 'degree' (defined like in polar coordinates)
    never intercepts with path. False otherwise."""
    ray_end_point = (point[0] + radius * cos(degree), point[1] + radius * sin(degree))
    for i in range(0, len(path), 2):
        j = (i + 2) % len(path)
        seg_point_0 = path[i:i+2]
        seg_point_1 = path[j:j+2]
        if indx != i and indx != j and intersect(point, ray_end_point, seg_point_0, seg_point_1):
            return False
    return True


def deleteInsidePoints(path, num_rays, cutoff=0.0):
    """For each point, calculates the proportion of rays that go from the point and never hit any
    part of the path again. If the proportion is strictly greater than the cutoff, the point is kept in the return list.
    Otherwise, it's ignored."""
    final = []
    max_len = ((min(path[::2]) - max(path[::2])) ** 2 + (min(path[1::2]) - max(path[1::2])) ** 2) ** 0.5
    for i in range(0, len(path), 2):
        point = path[i:i+2]
        num_escape = 0
        for j in range(num_rays):
            num_escape += int(rayEscape(point, 2 * pi * j / num_rays, path, max_len, i))
        if num_escape / num_rays > cutoff:
            final.extend(point)
    return final

lst2 = deleteInsidePoints(lst, 25, 0.3)
```

Here are two real-life applications:

[image: bad 1]
[image: good 1]

[image: bad 2]
[image: good 2]

In the second one, you can see it was a bit overzealous in deleting on the left side and left a straight line, but overall it's pretty good.

Side-note: My code here is edited slightly from the first time I posted it. I forgot to not have the program check if the ray intersected with segments of the path *including* the point the ray was coming from. Now, the "indx" variable in the `rayEscape` function allows skipping of segments that include the point of interest.

Comment: Thank you! Doubt anyone else will ever need this but I figured I might as well post it.

Comment: I think this information is ALWAYS useful. Somebody might have a similar problem, albeit, in a different context, and your answer might just get them closer to the solution they are looking for. After all, we are trying to build a repository of knowledge here! Thanks four your contribution.