# How to fit a plane to a 3D point cloud?

Tags: c++, 3d, linear-algebra, algebra, plane

I want to fit a plane to a 3D point cloud. I use a RANSAC approach, where I sample several points from the point cloud, calculate the plane, and store the plane with the smallest error. The error is the distance between the points and the plane. I want to do this in C++, using Eigen.

So far, I sample points from the point cloud and center the data. Now, I need to fit the plane to the samples points. I know I need to solve `Mx = 0`, but how do I do this? So far I have M (my samples), I want to know x (the plane) and this fit needs to be as close to 0 as possible.

I have no idea where to continue from here. All I have are my sampled points and I need more data.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400213/3d-least-squares-plane

Comment: No this is not a duplicate. Cassie is asking about fitting a plane in presence of outliers. The other question considers purely the least squares fit.

Answer (score 0):

From you question I assume that you are familiar with the Ransac algorithm, so I will spare you of lengthy talks.

In a first step, you sample three random points. You can use the [Random](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a8e759dafdd9ecc446d397b7f5435f60a) class for that but picking them not truly random usually gives better results. To those points, you can simply fit a plane using [Hyperplane::Through](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Hyperplane.html#aabfcda23a80edfd62387bb3d930f4b96).

In the second step, you repetitively cross out some points with large [Hyperplane::absDistance](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Hyperplane.html#a8383bb22fa5f6024856f2c781f6ec0db) and perform a least-squares fit on the remaining ones. It may look like this:

```
Vector3f mu = mean(points);
Matrix3f covar = covariance(points, mu);
Vector3 normal = smallest_eigenvector(covar);
JacobiSVD<Matrix3f> svd(covariance, ComputeFullU);
Vector3f normal = svd.matrixU().col(2);
Hyperplane<float, 3> result(normal, mu);
```

Unfortunately, the functions `mean` and `covariance` are not built-in, but they are rather straightforward to code.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the equation for a plane passing through origin is Ax + By + Cz = 0, where (x, y, z) can be any point on the plane and (A, B, C) is the normal vector perpendicular to this plane.

The equation for a general plane (that may or may not pass through origin) is Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, where the additional coefficient D represents how far the plane is away from the origin, along the direction of the normal vector of the plane. *[Note that in this equation (A, B, C) forms a unit normal vector.]*

Now, we can apply a trick here and fit the plane using only provided point coordinates. Divide both sides by D and rearrange this term to the right-hand side. This leads to A/D x + B/D y + C/D z = -1. *[Note that in this equation (A/D, B/D, C/D) forms a normal vector with length 1/D.]*

We can set up a system of linear equations accordingly, and then solve it by an Eigen solver as follows.

```
// Example for 5 points
Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 3> matA; // row: 5 points; column: xyz coordinates
Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 1> matB = -1 * Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 1>::Ones();

// Find the plane normal
Eigen::Vector3d normal = matA.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(matB);

// Check if the fitting is healthy
double D = 1 / normal.norm();
normal.normalize(); // normal is a unit vector from now on
bool planeValid = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { // compare Ax + By + Cz + D with 0.2 (ideally Ax + By + Cz + D = 0)
  if ( fabs( normal(0)*matA(i, 0) + normal(1)*matA(i, 1) + normal(2)*matA(i, 2) + D) > 0.2) {
    planeValid = false; // 0.2 is an experimental threshold; can be tuned
    break;
  }
}
```

This method is equivalent to the typical SVD-based method, but much faster. It is suitable for use when points are known to be roughly in a plane shape. However, the SVD-based method is more numerically stable (when the plane is far far away from origin) and robust to outliers.