# Getting the boundary of a hole in a 3d plane

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry

I have a set of 3d points that lie in a plane. Somewhere on the plane, there will be a hole (which is represented by the lack of points), as in this picture:

[image]

I am trying to find the contour of this hole. Other solutions out there involve finding convex/concave hulls but those apply to the outer boundaries, rather than an inner one.

Is there an algorithm that does this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the plane (which you could determine by PCA), you can project all points into this plane and continue with the 2D coordinates. Thus, your problem reduces to finding boundary points in a 2D data set.

Your data looks as if it might be uniformly sampled (independently per axis). Then, a very simple check might be sufficient: Calculate the centroid of the - let's say 30 - nearest neighbors of a point. If the centroid is very far away from the original point, you are very likely on a boundary.

A second approach might be recording the directions in which you have neighbors. I.e. keep something like a bit field for the discretized directions (e.g. angles in 10° steps, which will give you 36 entries). Then, for every neighbor, calculate its direction and mark that direction, including a few of the adjacent directions, as occupied. E.g. if your neighbor is in the direction of 27.4°, you could mark the direction bits 1, 2, and 3 as occupied. This additional surrounding space will influence how fine-grained the result will be. You might also want to make it depend on the distance of the neighbor (i.e. treat the neighbors as circles and find the angular range that is spanned by the circle). Finally, check if all directions are occupied. If not, you are on a boundary.

Alpha shapes can give you both the inner and outer boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

1. **convert to 2D by projecting the points onto your plane**

   see related **QA** dealing with this:

   - [C++ plane interpolation from a set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45431861/2521214)
2. **find holes in 2D point set**

   simply apply this related **QA**:

   - [Finding holes in 2d point sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816562/finding-holes-in-2d-point-sets)
3. **project found holes back to 3D**

   again see the link in **#1**

Sorry for almost link only answer but booth links are here on **SO/SE** and deals exactly with your issue when combined. I was struggling first to flag your question as duplicate and leave this in a comment but this is more readable.