# Best way to solve a linear equation in code

Tags: .net, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving a linear equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769/solving-a-linear-equation)

I need to programmatically solve a system of linear equations in C# AND VB

Here's an example of the equations:

```
 12.40 = a * 56.0 + b * 27.0 + tx
-53.39 = a * 12.0 + b * 59.0 + tx
 14.94 = a * 53.0 + b * 41.0 + tx
```

I'd like to get the best approximation for a, b, and tx.

Should i use some sort of matrix class or something?

Comment: You say best approximation, so do you know that your matrix will always be square and well-conditioned?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769/solving-a-linear-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think we've seen this question already: [Solving a linear equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769/solving-a-linear-equation)

Comment: The language is slightly different, but the method is the same and we seem to be talking about algorithms anyway, so yeah, there's nothing new in this question.

Comment: Comments. Identification of duplicates belong in the comments.

Comment: I would argue this is NOT a duplicate. C, Objective C and C++ have completely different libraries than C#. Come on, this is not something you want to do yourself. Re-use, re-use and re-use!

Answer (score 4):

Gauss-Jordan elimination is the most straightforward and easiest to understand method for solving a system of simultaneous linear equations like this.  LU decomposition is a little more numerically stable, but your matrix doesn't look poorly conditioned so I don't think you need the extra complexity.

Comment: Gaussian Elimination was what I meant to say, but at 3.55am, for some reason my head said Simplex! Rectified. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: ah yes, simplex has a step involving gaussian elimination, the other steps are used to determine which combinations of equations give a solution in the feasible region, and to move to adjacent vertices in the direction of improved goal function.  Of course, I have the advantage that it's only 10PM here and my brain is not yet such a fuzz.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the coefficients in a matrix, you can solve it by computing the LU decomposition of the matrix.  I'm not terribly familiar with the exact algorithm, but wikipedia's pages on this should be a good starting point:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Answer (score 2):

Use [Cramer's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) It is easy to solve linear equations by this rule.

To solve matrices use http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSML.aspx