# Realize equations with C#

Tags: c#, equation

How can I realize a equations like this in C# with custom inputs?

Input is amount of Legs, and the amount of animals.

```
animals: 35
legs: 94

x: Cows
y: Hens

Amount of animals
x + y = 35
y = 35 - x

Amount of legs
Hens: 2 legs
Cows: 4 legs

4x + 2y = 94

->

4x + 2y = 94
4x + 2(35 - x) = 94
4x + 70 - 2x = 94
2x = 24
x = 12

y = 35 - x = 35 - 12 = 23
```

-> 12 Cows
-> 23 Hens

Comment: You want to display each step of the computation?

Comment: This question is by far too broad. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Try to do any research. We don't want to write the ready-to-use program for you, we are not programming service.

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to code quadratic equations in C#? The starting point is that you know that for class Cow.Legs == 4 & Hen.Legs == 2. Then do you wish to determine the number of Cows and Hens if the total number of animals is 35 and the total number of legs is 94?

Comment: Is there any function which can do that?

Comment: I guess you already know about linear equation and thier matrices and vectors equivalent. There should be a lot of project around on the net solving this on fortran, basic, c, c++. The simple resolution of the equation could be done by all math library.

Comment: related : [Best way to solve a linear equation in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383959/), [Solving a linear equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution applies if you have only these two types of animals.

```
int animals = 35;
int legs = 94;
int x = (legs - 2*animals)/2;
int y = animals -x;
Console.WriteLine(x + " Cows and " + y + " hens");
```

If you want to solve linear equation, then you can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769/solving-a-linear-equation)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that this was so easy