# opencv or javacv or other

Tags: opencv, javacv

I am developing **face detection photo capture application** in android. Some one said that use of opencv native camera is the best to capture face. I heard javacv also to capture face. Can anyone tell what is the best method **opencv** (or) **javacv** (or) other than these two. 
Thanks.

Comment: Q: Which is better: "chocolate" or "vanilla"?  Take a look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769

Comment: PS: All things being equal, and assuming you're comfortable with Java programming on the Android, the link I cited suggests that you're probably "better off" using JavaCV.  IMHO...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCV has an official version for android in which you program in Java. It is usually named OpenCV4Android.

JavaCV is a non-official Java version of OpenCV.

Writing native code using Android NDK will usually be much faster than using the SDK. Face detection must be faster in opencv than javacv.

My advice is for you to use OpenCV4Android, it will be easier for you, and also has more documentation: **https://opencv.org/platforms/android/**

Comment: Thanks. I am proceeding with opencv. It is working for face detection photo capture .

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV now has bindings for desktop Java, make a look at [this](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html)

**From the link:**

> This has two major advantages:
>
> - The Java wrapper is automatically kept up-to-date.
> - The bindings closely match the original C++ interface. 
>          More information is available in the new [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)...

Answer (score 0):

`OpenCV` is a very good Computer visio library. It has `C`, `C++` and `Python` API. `JavaCV` is Wrapper of `OpenCV` using java.

based on your purpose you can use native C API using Android NDK. If you are focus on Java then you can use `JavaCV`.