# OpenCV with JavaCV or only OpenCV to use java API

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I am a new to OpenCV library and I would like to use the Java API for openCV.
I read instructions in websites regarding how to install openCV and use it as a library in Eclipse.

Now what confuses me is, as I want to program in Java should i use JavaCv? or only openCV as the latter has java API as well?

kindly please clarify this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [opencv or javacv or other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919961/opencv-or-javacv-or-other)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 2.4.4 [OpenCV supports Java](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html). You will find a jar in the OpenCV/build/java folder. For details, see [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html#java-eclipse) about using OpenCV Java with Eclipse.

So my answer is, use only OpenCV, as described in the tutorial, not JavaCV.

cheers

Comment: thanks, is there any recommended tutorial regarding hoe to use opencv with java and android?

Comment: Check this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html