# Solving a linear equation with jQuery

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to solve the following linear equation with jQuery.

12.5x = 20 + x + (20 + x)/10
(Note that 12.5, 20, and 10 are numbers provided by user)

Is there a way in jQuery to get x?
Thank you very much

Comment: You don't need jQuery, regular JavaScript would do just fine. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery or any other language. There are plenty of threads in the "related" section to your right disucssing this topic e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769/solving-a-linear-equation?rq=1. I think the problem you are facing is the underlaying maths, not the API/language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your problem is purely related to Math

Assume you equation is of format:

```
ax = b + x + (c + x) / d;
```

Hence the solution is:

```
var x = (b * d + c) / (a * d - d - 1);
```

if `b === c` then, solution is:

```
var x = (b * d + b) / (a * d - d - 1);
```

Comment: I think `b` and `c` are the same parameter.

Comment: @PawelZubrycki me too, so I provide also solution for that, Thanks.